# How can I set a timer in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, timer, windows-8.1

In C#, I want to set a timer when entering the page, then have a ten second countdown begin.

If the user does not complete the operation within ten seconds, the timer is triggered, suggesting "game over".

If the user has completed the operation within ten seconds, then the timer device is canceled.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DispatcherTimer` class. The `tick` event handler should have the code that says game over.

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((DispatcherTimer)sender).Stop();
    //Your code here
}
```

Whenever the user just completed his operations, you can just call `dispatcherTimer.Stop();`. This will stop the timer.

Comment: Note that `DispatcherTimer` is preferable here, because it will automatically keep the timer event on the UI thread where it probably needs to be (hard to know from the vaguely worded question). But just to be complete, it's worth mentioning that in this scenario where a "one-shot" timer is desired, other than the thread-affinity issue, the [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7(v=vs.110).aspx) class offers that behavior directly, without the need to stop the timer after the first event/callback is raised.

Comment: Can I get Time left ? I want to display Time left ,Accuracy is 0.1 seconds

Comment: Its not completely accurate. One option is to change the interval to 100 milliseconds, then increment a counter variable for every tick. p.s. Don't call `DispatcherTimer.Stop()` in the tick function if you are gonna do this.

Comment: For calculating time left, store a `DateTime` variable when you start the timer. Then, whenever you want, find the difference between `DateTime.Now` and your previously stored `DateTime` object to get the time elapsed.

Comment: @HanqingYang Did you try this to change the accuracy?